# Getting all links on a page that match a url string

Tags: javascript, mootools, string-matching

I'm currently using this code (along with Mootools) to build an array of all anchors in the `#subnav` div that contain a specific url string:

`$('subnav').getElements('a[href*=/'+href+']')`

Problem is if I'm looking for `work.aspx?subsection=24&project=1` that will match anchors with a URL of `work.aspx?subsection=24&project=15`.

How can I prevent that from happening?

Comment: Can you clarify what it is you want "contain" to mean here? What exactly should it mean for an href value to "contain" the URL string (fragment of a URL?  not clear) you're searching for?

Comment: `console.log(document.getElements("a[href$=work.aspx?subsection=24&project=1]"));` - ends on, not contains which won't pickup project=15.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going to answer my own question. It was as simple as changing the `*` to a `$`.

`$('subnav').getElements('a[href$=/'+href+']')`

Comment: perhaps because of `Going to answer my own question.` when the _same_ answer had been posted as a comment some 8 hours earlier.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I can think of is to use regexes; something like this:

```
$('subnav').getElements('a').filter(function (element, index) {
    return /work\.aspx\?subsection=24&project=1(?:$|&)/.test(element.href);
});
```

That regex will match project=1 and then either a `&` or the end of the string. It uses MooTool's (or the native browser's) `Array.filter` to remove all non-matches. It isn't the most elegant solution, especially if you are using this dynamically, since then you'd have to write some code to create a new regex.

Comment: It is also a very expensive operation :)

Comment: Agreed, but it's the only thing I could think of to solve the issue.

Comment: Hmm. Yeah, I can't really afford expensive. The site's already incredibly heavy in the JS.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this should be handled more gracefully by a 301 or 302 redirect...

Comment: Not sure why. I'm not trying to redirect anyone.

Comment: But isn't that exactly what you're doing by changing the URLs through Javascript? Google will still end up following ...&project=1. Maybe I just don't understand your problem thoroughly enough...

Comment: I'm not changing any URLs. I'm looking for anchors that match a the url of the current page and adding a "here" class to those anchors. I would normally do this server-side, but this site is full-on ajax.